# Did the Ancients ever use their time-travel machine?

Tags: stargate

In Stargate SG1 we find out that the Ancients mastered time travel at some point. SG1 discover the time machine and the Ancient ship but is there anything out there that explains what happened to this Ancient? Or what else he did?

If one Ancient mastered time travel then clearly the others must have known. Is it possible they used the device to go back and change there history or move to the future/past and live out there lives there?

Comment: This is touched on again briefly in Stargate Atlantis if I remember correctly.

Comment: @Xantec Yes, there [is an episode](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Before_I_Sleep) where Weir meets him in an alternate timeline.  It is implied that what she tells him is what leads him to make the one found in SG-1, which would make it occur before the point in time Corey seems to be asking about

Answer (score 6):

In the SGA episode "[Before I Sleep](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/Before_I_Sleep)" we learn that the Ancient known as Janus is the one who created the puddle-jumper time machine. It would appear that his efforts were universally **condemned** by the other Ancients, *despite* the fact that their city was under constant attack and their colonies and outposts in ruins.

> **MOROS:** *No. Enough of this tampering with time. Causality is not to be treated so lightly.*
>
> **JANUS:** *No-one's treating it lightly.*
>
> **MOROS:** *You are, with your insistence on continuing with experiments -- despite the condemnation of this Council. We ordered
>   you to cease these activities and yet here we sit, face to face with a
>   visitor from the future who arrived here in the very machine you
>   agreed not to construct.*

When Weir arrives in a time-jumper, The Council of Ancients immediately destroy it. Janus manages to get Weir back to her original time (kinda) by traveling the long way around, placing her into a stasis pod with instructions on how to prevent the city from drowning, as it did in her original timeline.

His parting words are that **he intends to continue his efforts to create a time-ship**, efforts that were obviously successful given that SG1 subsequently locates and uses it. There is, however, no special indication that he used the ship himself to escape into the past or the future:

> (In Central Control, Past-Elizabeth is lurking out of sight of the
>   departing Atlanteans. Janis is removing some glass control panels from
>   the consoles and putting them into a carrying case.)
>
> **PAST-WEIR:** *What's all that?*
>
> **JANUS:** *My research.*
>
> **WEIR:** *You're gonna build another time ship.*

Answer (score 0):

In SG1's "It's Good To Be King", a functioning Timeship is found on "Maybourne's World".  Writings in Ancient also on that planet indicate that the timeship was used.